# on_member_update not triggerring

Tags: python, discord.py

Intents are enabled on discord developer portal, but it still isn't triggering

```
import discord
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.presences = True

@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    print('working')
```

Comment: Your client is not defined.

Comment: It is. What I posted is obviously just a small bit of code. The whole code is about 600 lines long

Comment: It would be best if we could see that you defined the intents in your client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like this

```
intents = discord.Intents().all()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '[your prefix here]', intents = intents)
```